# Store file inside VBA Project and open it

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA Application in MS Excel 2010. It has one user form. There I'd like to add a feature to open a (MS Word) file for support and FAQ purposes. I do not want to save the file at a central location and open the file then via VBA. Is there a possibility to store the file maybe inside the vba project?

Comment: I dont think thats possible out of the box.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could store the file in the Excel zip file... any solution would be highly appreciated..

Comment: what do you mean by _excel zip file_

Comment: Do you need pictures? if you do not need pictures you can just save giant HTML string as a .doc and word takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed an object in an Excel Worskeet (Insert -> Object). If you click on the embedded object, in the upper left corner you will see the name of the object (e.g. "Object 7"). With that you can open it in vba via

```
Sub openEmbed()
  Dim ole As OLEObject, wdoc As Word.Document
  Set ole = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Object 7")
  ole.Activate
  Set wdoc = ole.Object
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the content as XML in the VBA and then insert it with `InsertXML` in a new document:

```
Dim app As Object
Set app = CreateObject("Word.Application")

app.Visible = True

app.Documents.Add.Content.InsertXML "<?xml version=""1.0""?><abc:books xmlns:abc=""urn:books"" " & _
  "xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " & _
  "xsi:schemaLocation=""urn:books books.xsd""><book>" & _
  "<author>Matt Hink</author><title>Migration Paths of the Red " & _
  "Breasted Robin</title><genre>non-fiction</genre>" & _
  "<price>29.95</price><pub_date>2006-05-01</pub_date>" & _
  "<abstract>You see them in the spring outside your windows.  " & _
  "You hear their lovely songs wafting in the warm spring air.  " & _
  "Now follow their path as they migrate to warmer climes in the fall, " & _
  "and then back to your back yard in the spring.</abstract></book></abc:books>"
```